Do there exist non-isomorphic graphs with same set of vertex degrees?
In my graph theory lecture, I became interested in the following problem while doodling some graphs. Can I draw two non-isomorphic graphs which each have vertices of the same degree? After a few minutes I found a solution:

Another way to phrase this problem is integer partitions of $2n$. In the above case, we partitioned $8 = (1,2,2,3)$ into two non isomorphic graphs. I found this particular case can be generalized:
$$2n = (1,2,2,2, \ldots, 3).$$
Note that we cannot partition odd numbers because the sum of the degrees will always be even (as every edge connects two vertices).
My question is: is this the only such way to complete this problem? I tried with some effort to find other example, but I could not.

You might be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence

The rightmost label in the first graph should be $2$ instead of $1$.

Ah yeah your're right, good catch.

There are 5 different (nonisomorphic) graphs of order 10 in which every vertex has degree 2. Likewise there are 5 different graphs of order 10 in which every vertex has degree 7.

The number of nonisomorphic connected graphs with $2n$ vertices, every vertex having degree three, is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A002851 – you will see that the number gets very large very fast. With $n=20$, it's $8832736318937756165$.

No. Another minimal example (by vertex count) has $5$ vertices: Both the path graph $P_5$ and the disjoint union $K_2 \oplus K_3$ have degree sequence $(1,1,2,2,2)$. If you prefer connected graphs, you can simply take the complements of these graphs, namely $P_5'$ and $K_{2, 3}$, which have degree sequence $(2,2,2,3,3)$. These two examples, together with the example in the question statement, exhaust all of the examples on $5$ vertices. These examples can be generalized to graphs with more vertices in the natural way.
$P_5'$: $\quad$  $\qquad\qquad$ $K_{2, 3}$:
(Illustrations from Peter Steinbach, Field Guide to Simple Graphs, 1, $\S$2.)
Already among graphs with $6$ edges there are $5$ nonisomorphic graphs with degree sequence $(1,1,2,2,3,3)$, and their duals are $5$ nonisomorphic graphs with degree sequence $(2,2,3,3,4,4)$.

Both of the graphs below have a degree set of {2,2}.
They are not isomorphic to each other.
The graph on the left has loops and is not connected.
The graph on the right has parallel edges and is connected.


Let's assume simple, connected graphs so this sort of thing doesn't happen.
